# Why is Mac supposedly better than Windows for graphics?

Tags: windows, mac

I keep hearing that if you're going to do serious work with graphics, design, et cetera, you should get a Mac.

What are some actual differences between the latest Mac OS X and the latest Windows in 2010 that would make it better to work on Mac OS X if you will be working with graphics and design?

Comment: This is a subjective question.

Comment: +1 it's not a subjective question. He's asking about "what that argument is about" not "Do you think Mac is better than Windows for graphics?"

Comment: @Josh K - No, it isn't. Mac up until recently had a different internal architecture, which was better fitted for the mentioned (it still differs in some aspects).

Comment: @Idigas: What aspects? And are they still there?

Comment: PowerPC was never better fitted for Adobe apps. Adobe pairs very well with Mac operating systems and hardware because it's designed that way. Then they are taken and squeezed on to the windows platform. There might not be visible changes but there are readily apparent performance ones.

Comment: @Yar: If it's not subjective (which it clearly is) then it's off topic. *To me it seems like their whole argument is based on that "everyone else does".*, *Anyways... What is the deal really? Is there actually any advantage in using Mac for graphics and design and such things?*, *So, can anyone give me a good explanation on this? Is there a real difference or are people just brainwashed?*, *My take is*, etc. **Verbal subjective cues**.

Comment: @Josh K, my belief is that the OP could be guided to pull out the non-subjective portion of the question. But I'll admit, it's a long shot :) But at least it's a CW...

Comment: I have tried to pull out the verbal subjective cues now. Hope it can be reopened, cause I really am curious to know what the differences are and why they make one system more fit than the other for this kind of work.

Comment: @Svish - without going into detail, search for differences in internal architectures of pc's and mac's. I don't have any links on me, but I gather it shouldn't be long, before you stumble on the topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use both Mac and Windows. Overall I would prefer to work on the Mac, but with Windows 7 the differences are getting to be razor thin. Adobe used to have serious issues on Windows, but those are entirely gone. The Mac/Win versions of Adobe's CS5, for example, are only related to the differences between windowing and menu handling on each platform.

There are only a few areas where there exist clear advantages for one side or the other now.

**Advantage Mac**

- The finder window column view
- Folder shortcuts that are part of the
  window frame, not a list, and are
  hence easy to drag/drop to, etc.
- Control-arrow changes  your window set (I can't remember what this is called atm, although I use it every day).
- Some really decent Mac-only apps. Also, iTunes is *way* faster.
- Better mouse "feel" for doing graphics. More precise control, better start/stop easing.
- You can run Windows on Mac, but you can't run a Mac on Windows.

**Advantage Windows 7**

- Edge-resizable windows (I mean, come on, this is just better)
- The Taskbar implementation has finally beaten out the Mac's dock
- Better implementation of mouse right-button
- More software to select from, and almost everything you want to use has a Windows version at least; many, many useful programs have no Mac ports.

Comment: +1 for Windows 7 taskbar.  I would kill to have that on my Mac.

Comment: What programs do you need on Windows that aren't available in comprable Mac programs?

Comment: I'm not saying there aren't *comparable* programs. I'm just saying if you have favorite programs on Windows they won't necessarily have ports on the Mac. I've gotten used to WinMerge, for example, and it's not ported to the Mac, so I have to use DiffMerge. Not bad, just different. I like it best when I can use programs that have identical versions on either system, like the Adobe products or, say, ActiveState's KomodoEdit.

Answer (score 2):

It's a perception that was objectively true back in the days when desktop publishing was an emerging field and ColorSync was an amazing new technology, but these days it's largely a question of preference. I, and many others, find the Windows versions of Photoshop and Illustrator utterly bizarre and non-conducive to productivity. People who've never used anything else will have a different opinion.

Comment: "utterly bizarre and non-conducive to productivity"? what do you mean by that? I have used Photoshop on both windows and on mac, and I saw no real difference.

Comment: As for me I had plenty of trouble adjusting to the Mac version of PS since keyboard shortcuts for the menu and individual controls in dialogs (something I used heavily back then) didn't exist ;). +1 for the answer though, since it's by now really a non-issue unless you're dependent on Apple Foobar Pro software which doesn't exist for Windows.

Comment: I absolutely disagree with you, from my little time with PS on a mac I found myself pining for a taskbar again. Which just proves your point - it's all preference these days.

Comment: Yeah, keyboard shortcuts and differences like that is an issue. But like @Phoshi, that is only about preferences and what you're used to. Which is exactly my point and why I am asking if there is any *real* differences.

Comment: Josh K's answer (in comment#3 to your question) - essentially, "once, but no longer" - sounds the most reasonable (ignoring, for the moment, that it undercuts his criticism 2 comments earlier...)

Comment: Back in the day it was all about CRT colour calibration, somehow this has got distorted and people seem to have some false impression that the hardware is somehow optimised for graphics.